# Diagonal line-through Text React-Native

Tags: react-native

I am looking for a way to make a diagonal line through a text element on react-native.

with an :after element and css this should be possible but this is not available in react-native.

Anybody cool suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eventually, I went for a situation where I drew an absolute positioned line with a rotation on it.

```
<View
                style={{
                    position: 'absolute',
                    transform: [ {rotate: '17deg'} ],
                    top: 7,
                    width: 25,
                    height: 1,
                    borderBottomColor: styleGuide.errorColorRed,
                    borderBottomWidth: 1,
                }}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make strick in text you should use something like this

```
<Text style={{ textDecorationLine: 'line-through' }}>$12</Text>
```

Comment: also u can use this two props textDecorationColor: color (iOS)

textDecorationStyle: enum('solid', 'double', 'dotted', 'dashed') (iOS)

Comment: Sure but this will make it a horizontal line.
I am looking for a way to make diagonal line-through. Thanks anyhow.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
style={{ textDecorationLine: 'line-through' }}
```